# Does Berkeley DB Java Edition support non-equal search?

Tags: java, database, search, berkeley-db, key-value

I want to get data entries by key with non-equal operator , is that possible in Berkeley DB?
And is there any other alternatives fast k/v system implemented by java that supports non-equal search or range search?Thanks!

Comment: Range queries are definitely supported, not sure about negative searches, probably not.

Answer (score 1):

[Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/1.9.4/manual/single_html/#MapQuery) supports a large range of queries ans is very fast. We use it in production for 2 years now